# Find document by value without its reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nuxt.js

[image]

This is a database structure for my image uploading app. The first collection group is ID of the user, its childs are images, with IDs as titles.

I am trying to create a get route for example: `domain.com/i/IMAGE_ID`, then get that ID and provide image across the page.

Is it possible to find needed document without having the title of its parent?

Comment: Did you read the docs for Firestone? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to find needed document without having the title of its parent?

Yes it is possible using a query which is related to a property. Let's assume your know the file name, then please use the following lines of code:

```
var uidRef = firebase.database().ref("images").ref(uid);
var query = uidRef.orderByChild("fileName").equalTo("Colour7.jpg")
```

In which the `uid` is the id of the authenticated user. The result of the query will be the second item in your `images` node.

**Edit:**

If you only have the image `ID`, please use the following lines of code:

```
var uidRef = firebase.database().ref("images").ref(uid);
var query = uidRef.orderByChild("ID").equalTo("2sj2yAJN3MC24GwjLtDkt")
```

Comment: But I only have image ID from get params, no "uid".

Comment: In this case, please see my updated answer. Does it work now?